# Hinfinty Controller for TWO wheeled self balanicng robot

Tags: ros2, control, gazebo-11, two-wheeled

I'm trying to implement a H-infinity controller in a TWO-WHEELED-SELF-BALANCING-ROBOT, already implemented LQR for the same in gazebo, where the control input was torque(used this selfbalancing robot [gazebo model](https://github.com/robustify/teeterbot)) , But when it comes to H-infinity i have two inputs to give to the system, one control input and another is disturbance input, Any ideas on how to give the disturbance input?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your issue: What equation/algorithm you want to apply? 
Normally you have to find a model of your plant for controller synthesis, having exogenous inputs (like disturbances) and the manipulated variables u. Don't expect that you find this "disturbance input" to the gazebo model. But maybe I just don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use the [nudge service](https://github.com/robustify/teeterbot/tree/master/teeterbot_gazebo/srv) where you can specify the force to apply and the duration of the nudge.